# CSS - Google+ Box Positioning

Tags: css, positioning

I added the G+ box to the homepage and notice that when I increase or reduce the browser page size the website content stays on the same place - but the G+ box moves and covers the content. How can I fix the Badge relative to the content and not the browser?

Website [Here](http://www.docklandsstudios.ie)

The CSS:

```
html {
height:100%;
}

body {
background:#000;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height:100%!important;
min-height:750px;
min-width:980px;
}

object, embed {
vertical-align:top; min-height:750px; outline:none; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

div {
height: 100%;
}

img {
border:none; vertical-align:top
}

.aligncenter {
text-align:center;
}

.google {
right: 150px;
top: 600px;
position: fixed;
height: 60px;
border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the G+ box always in the same place, why not creating a relative positioned container for the flash and logo and an absolute positioned one inside for the G+? Your G+ box doesn´t need to have dynamic width (the flash is just centered but doesn´t change width) so you have no constrains there. Or am I missing something?

```
.container {
position:relative;
}
.google {
position:absolute;
left: 600px;
top: 600px;
height: 60px;
border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick (and maybe dirty) fix would be to specify the `right` and `top` or maybe `bottom` as percentages. ie `right: 15%` and `bottom: -1%` — that looked decent on my end.

Another solution could be to just write a bit of javascript code to fix the piece.
Something along the lines of

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var gHeight = $('.google').height();
var offset = parseInt(windowHeight) - parseInt(gHeight);
$('.google').css('top',offset);
```

I havent tested this code on your site. It's just meant as a general idea.

Comment: I tried the % suggestion but if the bw is small, the button covers the pages when opened... good shout though! Will try the .js and see what happens, although I'm no expert